# What should be the URL after deploying with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, capistrano

I ran instructions on [this website](http://www.leemunroe.com/deploy-rails-with-capistrano/) and everything went well. However, when I type in the URL, I get a 404 error. My server runs CentOS. Shouldn't I be able the access my Rails app via the URL I have defined in my deploy.rb file? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question is very ambiguous.  We have no idea what your environment is, where you deployed to, what your domain name is, what your IP address, or what you expect the URL to be.  Please clarify this.

Comment: My environment is centOs and I am trying to run a ruby on rails application. Does the app url equal to what you I have in the deploy.rb file? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL depends on how you configured your server. In order to serve a Rails app you need to have a web server installed (Thin, Mongrel, Passenger, Nginx...) and configure it to serve your Rails app.

The site will be available at the URL/IP you configured your web server host.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to deploying rails applications.